# Laravel 5.2 dynamic environment variables based on user

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, phpdotenv

In my **.env** file I have two variables

```
App_id: 12345
App_secret: abc123
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way so that if user `userNo2` logs in then it would instead use

```
App_id: 45678
App_secret: abc456
```

Is there a way to have **if/else** functionality in the `env` file based on the user?

Comment: No, you cant. You should using DB for each user. `.env file` just used when change value between develop and production environment

Comment: if you are trying this condition try a package for store value and package name is `STORAGE` because if you are login to store value in storage and get value only one time this package use cache and store value in cache one time goes to db and other time get value from cache try this

Comment: this is a perfect scenario for adding additional columns to the `users` table and storing that info there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but not in the `.env` file. Instead, you can move your logic to middleware:

### Step 1: Add default values to the application config

Open your `app/config/app.php` and add your default values to the existing array.

```php
<?php

return [
    'APP_ID' => '45678',
    'APP_SECRET' => 'abc456',
    ...
];
```

### Step 2: Create a new Middleware

`php artisan make:middleware SetAppConfigForUserMiddleware`

Edit the file to look like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class SetAppConfigForUserMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
         $authorizedUser = Auth::user();

        if (!App::runningInConsole() && !is_null($authorizedUser)) {
            Config::set('app.APP_ID', 'appidOfUser' . $authorizedUser->name);
            Config::set('app.APP_SECRET', 'appsecretOfUser' . $authorizedUser->email);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

### Step 4: Run your middleware

If you need to set this config for the user in all the web routes you can add to the `$middlewareGroups` array in `app/Http/kernel.php`. This will apply the middleware to **all the routes inside `web.php`**.

```php
/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\SetAppConfigForUserMiddleware::class,        
    ],
```

### Step 5: Testing

For example, my `Auth:user()->name` is "John" and my `Auth:user()->email` is "john@example.com"

If you put this in your `resources/views/home.blade.php`

```
App Id Of User <code>{{config('app.APP_ID')}}</code>
App Secret Of User <code>{{config('app.APP_SECRET')}}</code>
```

The result will be `appidOfUserJohn` and `appsecretOfUserjohn@example.com`.

Comment: I've been looking for a straight answers for changing config on runtime for a few days now!, thanks for this post!

Answer (score 0):

`.env` can only store key-value.

Since `.env` is always used by config, you can use `Config::set('app.id', 45678);` to mutate the env at run time. You can place the code in your middleware, and the value will back to default after the request ends.